# Python is adding point zero at end post number to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am unable to get why point zero is adding at the end of the string post converting from int to string.

The below is the code which I am trying to convert:

```
df['attendees_num'].astype(str)
```

here attendees_num value is 20 but its giving output 20.0. can someone help me how do i convert it into 20 as string without .0 at end.?

Comment: How/where you are defining the DataFrame??

Comment: I am getting data from csv file.

Comment: You tried something like this? `df = pd.read_csv( file , dtype = {'attendees_num':int} ` or the columns isn't a `Int` ?

Comment: tried above but not working, ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 9

Comment: But, why you want without that `.0` , you can import as string?

Comment: i want to display like  attend_number % last year

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188298/discussion-between-asr-and-blaztix).

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
df['attendees_num'].astype(int).astype(str)
```

Comment: I have tried above one but getting error: raise ValueError('Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to '
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: You probably have `nan` values. You can replace them with 999 or something similar, transform your data type and then replace 999 with `nan` again, or else you can `dropna()` depending on your situation